# How to programmatically trigger keyboard events in Monaco Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

In writing a generative test suite for code editors, I'm trying to programmatically call the event handlers that handle `KeyboardEvent`'s in Monaco.
Making a `new KeyboardEvent({...})` and dispatching it on the textarea, or root editor element didn't work.

For example, how could we transition the editor through the following states:

1. Paste "abc" => `abc|`
2. Move Cursor by -1 => `ab|c`
3. Delete once => `a|c`
4. Type "x" => `ax|c`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
editor.trigger(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd + monaco.KeyCode.KEY_P, 'type', { text: 'some text' });
```

Answer (score 0):

get a list of all supported actions using this code:

```js
  editor.getSupportedActions().forEach((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    });
```

there is some example of **trigger** function in Monaco-editor that may be suitable for you:

```js
editor.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: 'abc'})

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'deleteLeft', null);

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'deleteRight', null);

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'selectAll', null);

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'tab', null);

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'deleteLeft', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'cursorEnd', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'cursorHome', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'cursorTop', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'cursorBottom', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'undo', null)

editor.trigger('keyboard', 'redo', null)

editor.trigger('source', 'editor.action.formatDocument', null)

editor.trigger('editor', 'gotoLine', {lineNumber: 10, column: 5})
```